# How does USAID facilitate public access to USAID-funded research publications (i.e., journal articles)?

Tags: research, usaidopen

I see that USAID provides public access to research data via DDL.

I don't see how it provides public access to USAID-funded journal articles, as required by Feb 2013 OSTP public access memo.

Does USAID plan to collect articles/manuscripts from authors and establish a repository giving full-text access to articles? (for example: after a 12-month embargo period)

Answer (score 2):

Current [USAID regulations](http://www.usaid.gov/sites/default/files/documents/1868/aidar_0.pdf) and [policies](http://www.usaid.gov/sites/default/files/documents/1868/540.pdf) require that all USAID funded reports be submitted to the [Development Experience Clearinghouse](http://dec.usaid.gov) at the end of the project. USAID is currently finalizing a Public Access Plan for federally funded research that will outline guidance for ensuring public access of articles resulting from USAID-funding.  Page 10 of USAID's existing [Scientific Research Policy](http://www.usaid.gov/policy/scientific-research) also references the pending formulation of this plan.